# Android Wear: Peek card background under clocks

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

I am trying to build an analog version of "Simple" watch face. Example code is clear enough, I based my code on SweepWatchFaceService.java, but when I set `.setBackgroundVisibility(WatchFaceStyle.BACKGROUND_VISIBILITY_PERSISTENT)`
on surface holder, it covers the clocks (canvas). Is there a simple way to render peek card background as a surface holder (watch face) background?

Comment: Dived in a little more and what I need to do is to get instance of peek card background to set it as a face background. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

The watch face is rendered as a wallpaper, while the notification backgrounds are rendered inside the top activity. As a results, the backgrounds are always over the watch face.

The reason you can show the digital watch face (if you set the `WatchFaceStyle` option) is because the top activity also renders that.